# Keycloak with Spring 'Invalid credentials' after login

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm having no luck in setting up a simple Spring gateway + oauth2 client with Keycloak standalone. The keycloack part of it works fine. Wireshark shows the token correctly generated.

[image]

The gateway security config is as follows. I'm still not sure whether there is a need to permitAll() the login callback url. Some guides suggest that it should be the case, others dont. I suspect the oauth provider manages that part behind the scenes. Nonetheless, with or without permitAll for the "/login/*" path, the result remains the same.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(e -> e.anyExchange().authenticated());
        http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

After login the redirect to https://localhost:9000/login seems incorrect, it should retry the original url, say https://localhost:9000/test-service/v1/listall/

---

EDIT

In order to rule out any misconfigurations, even tried a simplest possible gateway and api resource (un-authenticated) and setup simplest possible relam in keyclock. The results haven't changed :( There are dozens of articles out there doing the exact same thing.

### [image]

Any pointers, ideas?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it was an incorrect user-name-attribute. The correct value is

```
user-name-attribute: preferred_username
```

For some reason, I had it set to preferred_name. It would save a lot of debug-time if only spring oauth writes the actual error instead of a generic invalid_grant.

Answer (score 1):

Even I have completed all configurations including "creating a client", "creating a scope" and creating a "user" with this scope. I have encountered this issue again.

The only solution worked for me is adding `scope :openid` to **application.yaml**.

You can refer application.yaml Security OAuth config from here:

```
 security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://${keycloak.base.url}/auth/realms/${realm}
      client:
        registration:
          gateway:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: ${client id}
            client-secret:${client secret}
            scope: openid
        provider:
          keycloak:
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
            issuer-uri: https://${keycloak.base.url}/auth/realms/${realm}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to offical doc(found at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter), you should use

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

Comment: As an OAuth authorization server, it should be possible to integrate with spring without an adapter. I would prefer not to use any vendor specific adapter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for anyone troubleshooting Spring Security, I recommend enabling debug logging by setting the logging level in your application.properties or application.yml file.

application.properties format:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

application.yml format:

```
logging:
    level:
        org:
            springframework:
                security: DEBUG
```

I was having a similar issue when using OAuth2 along with Spring Session. Even after authenticating successfully with Keycloak, I would get this login error whenever my Spring Session had expired.

I do not condone messing around with authentication flows, but I was able to resolve this issue by setting my own authentication entry point on the `ServerHttpSecurity`:

```
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/oauth2/authorization/keycloak"));
```

I then had to handle any requests to the "/login" page in my Controller. For me, I just redirect to my default landing page for a root request:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RootController {
    
    @GetMapping({"", "login"})
    public Mono<String> index() {
        return Mono.just("redirect:/myLandingPage");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow adding the "scope=openid" in my applications.properties works fine for me

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-client.scope=openid
```